# C# Unity ,foreach de prefabs

Tags: c#, xml, unity3d

Buenas.
Tengo una funcion que lee datos de un xml que es esta:

```
private string xmlPath;

    public XmlManager(string xmlPath) {
        this.xmlPath = xmlPath;
}
 public Datos ReadXmlTest() {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Datos));
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(xmlPath);
        Datos data = (Datos)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();

        return data;
    }
```

lo que ago con eso es conseguir unas rutas de unas fotos y guardar todas las rutas en data.

Luego tengo esta clase

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using UnityEngine;

public class AppButton : MonoBehaviour {

    private Juego game;

    public void Init(Juego game) {
        this.game = game;

    }

    private void RunApp() {
        Process.Start(game.ruta);
    }
}
```

y luego tengo esta clase donde esta el foreach

```
private Datos data;
    public GameObject Button;

    void Awake() {
        string path = "C:/Users/datos.xml";
        XmlManager xmlMng = new XmlManager(path);

        data = xmlMng.ReadXmlTest();

        foreach (var juego in data.Juegos) {
            GameObject newButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(Button);
            newButton.GetComponent<AppButton>();
            //
            //

        }
    }
```

En la ultima clase donde estan las // tengo que LLamar al Init de AppButton con juego pero no se como hacerlo.
Y aparte de eso como puedo hacer que por cada elemento que alla en el xml,se cree un boton con la imagen que hay en las rutas de los xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tomeselo como pseudocode, pero mas o menos esto creo que es lo que busca:

```
    //..
    foreach (var juego in data.Juegos) {

        GameObject newButton = (GameObject)Instantiate(Button);

        //newButton.GetComponent<AppButton>();
        //
        //

        string FilePath <- segun entiendo usted tiene en Datos las rutas,
                           pues la mete aqui la ruta si esta cambia en
                           cada iterecion tiene que cambiarla tambien
                           para que cambie la ruta de la imagen

        Sprite imageSprite = new Sprite();

        //Usamos el metodo para crear la textura
        Texture2D SpriteTexture = CTextura(FilePath); 

        //creamos es sprite
        imageSprite = Sprite.Create(SpriteTexture, new Rect(0, 0, SpriteTexture.width, SpriteTexture.height),new Vector2(0,0),100.0f);

        //newButton.GetComponent<AppButton>().image.sprite = imageSprite;

        newButton.image.sprite = imageSprite;//<- añadimos la imagen/sprite
        newButton.GetComponent<AppButton>().Init(Juego game)// <- tiene pasarle el parametro del tipo Juego


    }
}


public Texture2D CTextura(string Path) {

     Texture2D Texura2D;
     byte[] FileData;

     if (File.Exists(Path)){

       FileData = File.ReadAllBytes(Path);
       Texura2D = new Texture2D(2, 2);  

       if (Texura2D.LoadImage(FileData))           
         return Textura2D;                 
     }  
     return null;                     
}
```

Quizas le interese saber sobre [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html)